# wget: downloading all files in directories/subdirectories

Tags: linux, shell, wget

Basically on a webpage there is a list of directories, and each of these has further subdirectories. The subdirectories contain a number of files, and I want to download to a single location on my linux machine one file from each subdirectory which has the specific sequence letters 'RMD' in it.

E.g., say the main webpage links to directories dir1, dir2, dir3..., and each of these has subdirectories dir1a, dir1b..., dir2a, dir2b... etc. I want to download files of the form:

```
webpage/dir1/dir1a/file321RMD210
webpage/dir1/dir1b/file951RMD339
...
webpage/dir2/dir2a/file416RMD712
webpage/dir2/dir2b/file712RMD521
```

The directories/subdirectories are not sequentially numbered like in the above example (that was just me making it simpler to read) so is there a terminal command that will recursively go through each directory and subdirectory and download every file with the letters 'RMD' in the file name?

The website in question is: [here](http://atmos.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mslrem_1001/DATA/)

I hope that's enough information.

Comment: is there a directory listing on the website? or is it just files in a folder? If there is no public listing, you can't know what files exist. If there is a file listing, you'll need to do something to take that list, extract each url, visit them, extract each url.. etc. There are definitely tools you can find online to crawl a website from a certain url which will probably do this, however I cannot name or recommend any.

Comment: I have added the website link to the main post. I can manually go to each directory/subdirectory and download each file, but this would take a long time. Additionally, it would be useful to know how to automatically do this for the future.

Answer (score 3):

An answer with a lot of remarks:

> In case the website **supports ftp**, you better use [**@MichaelBaldry's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32569987/67579). This answer aims to give a way to do it with `wget` (but this is less efficient for both server and client).

**Only in case the website works with a directory listing**, you can use the `-r` flag for this (the `-R` flag aims to find links in webpages and then downloads these pages as well).

> The following method is **inefficient for both server and client** and can result in a huge load if the pages are generated dynamically. The website you mention furthermore **specifically asks not to fetch data that way**.

```
wget  -e robots=off -r -k -nv -nH -l inf -R jpg,jpeg,gif,png,tif --reject-regex '(.*)\?(.*)'  --no-parent 'http://atmos.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mslrem_1001/DATA/'
```

with:

- `wget` the program you want to call;
- `-e robots=off`; the fact that you ignore the websites request not to download this automatically;
- `-r`: you download recursively;
- `-R jpg,jpeg,gif,png,tif`: reject the downloading of media (the small images);
- `--reject-regex '(.*)\?(.*)'` do not follow or download query pages (sorting of index pages).
- `-l inf`: that you keep downloading for an infinite level
- `--no-parent`: prevent `wget` from starting to fetch links in the parent of the website (for instance the `..` links to the parent directory).

> `wget` downloads the files *breadth-first* so you will have to wait a long time before it eventually starts fetching the real data files.

> Note that `wget` has no means to *guess* the directory structure at server-side. It only aims to find links in the fetched pages and thus with this knowledge aims to generate a dump of "visible" files. It is possible that the webserver does not list all available files, and thus `wget` will fail to download all files.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed this site supports FTP protocol, which is a far more convenient way of reading files and folders. (Its for transferring files, not web pages)

Get a FTP client (lots of them about) and open ftp://atmos.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mslrem_1001/DATA/ you can probably just highlight all the folders in there and hit download.

Answer (score 2):

One solution using [`saxon-lint`](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) :

```
saxon-lint --html --xpath 'string-join(//a/@href, "^M")' http://atmos.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mslrem_1001/DATA/ | awk '/SOL/{print "http://atmos.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mslrem_1001/DATA/"$0}' | while read url; do saxon-lint --html --xpath 'string-join(//a/@href, "^M")' "$url" | awk -vurl="$url" '/SOL/{print url$0}'; done | while read url2; do saxon-lint --html --xpath 'string-join(//a/@href, "^M")' "$url2" | awk -vurl2="$url2" '/RME/{print url2$0}'; done | xargs wget
```

Edit the

```
"^M"
```

by <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (Unix) or `\r\n` for windows